# `Unexpected token import` in `webpack.config.babel.js` when using `{modules: false}`

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-2

I have a React project which uses Webpack as the module bundler, and `babel-loader` to transform it into ES5, using the following settings:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

The options are set in a stand-alone `.babelrc` file.

Babel [6.13.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v6130-2016-08-04) supports ECMAScript modules, which means ECMAScript modules doesn't need to be transformed into CommonJS modules first. To get this behaviour, the documentation says that we should use this setting in our `.babelrc`.

```
{
  presets: [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react"]
}
```

However, when I try to run Webpack using this setting, it comes back with the error:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
/home/d4nyll/foo/bar/webpack.config.babel.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import webpack from 'webpack';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I'm guessing this is because `babel-loader` doesn't act on `webpack.config.babel.js`, and so it's not recognising the `import` keyword. The error does not appear when `{ "modules": false }` is removed, but I want that functionality. How can I get Babel to recognise `webpack.config.babel.js`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following worked for me.

Set `.babelrc` to the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

The `.babelrc` settings would apply to the `webpack.config.babel.js` file.

Next, change the Webpack configuration to include the options you want applied to your application code.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            "presets": [["es2015", {"modules": false}], "react"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: The settings in your webpack config will be overridden by your .babelrc file unless you set `babelrc: false`

Comment: @yujingz That doesn't seem to be the case, I just got this working 100% without that

Comment: You will get the same error if you run `webpack --config ./webpack.config.babel`, to fix it run  `webpack --config ./webpack.config.babel.js` 

You need to add 'js' to the config file

Comment: @d4nyll the `env` preset is recommended by Babel over all others

Answer (score 11):

Just to emphasize, as you probably know: Your error

```
`Unexpected token import` in `webpack.config.babel.js`...
```

has *nothing* to do with the thing you are building, solely with your `webpack.config.babel.js`. Despite its name, ES6 is not gonna work without a few things made sure.

### Things to make sure:

1) [you don't need any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276592/444255) `webpack.config.js`, when you have a `webpack.config.babel.js` in your project.

2) make sure in your `package.json`, you are on Webpack Version 3 or higher for (1) to hold true

3) make sure you have a `.babelrc` containing at least `env` or `es2015`

```
{ "presets": ["env"] }
```

4) make sure to have the following two installed

```
npm install babel-cli --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Respectively `babel-preset-es2015` depending on your `.babelrc`. ([read here](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#babel-preset-env----) why `env` is arguably a bit cooler.)

Comment: true. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Webpack 2.6+ where `import` is baked in, make sure you use this babel plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

Answer (score -1):

You have created a webpack.config.js and when tying to execute `webpack` you are getting above error. Cause your webpack config file need to be `babelified` before you can use it,

1) Rename your `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.babel.js`.

2) Now create a new file `webpack.config.js` with just the following **2 lines**

```
require('babel-register');
module.exports = require('./webpack.config.babel.js');
```

3) create a `.babelrc` file in parallel to your `webpack.config.js` file with following content. We need to tell babel explicitly what preset to use.

```
{
  "presets": ["latest",'react', 'es2015','stage-2']
}
```

4) add following node modules to your dependency ( Required for presets used in `.babelrc`)

```
npm install babel-preset-env babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 babel-preset-latest babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

5) You are done . Now if you execute `webpack --progress --colors --watch` it should work.

Comment: ad 2) No `webpack.config.js` is needed (not even as a stub), if a `webpack.babel.config.js` is around. [See here[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239512/how-come-webpack-directly-imports-webpack-config-babel-js/46276592#46276592)

The `.babelrc` indeed is required (if you want to put ES6 into that file, which is the whole reason behind it...).