# Nextjs Reactjs: Unexpected token '<' Error when using eslint

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, next.js

I am working on a Nextjs-React application, and am getting this error when I run `npm run lint` Error: `../../Projects/app/pages/index.js ESlint Parsing error: Unexpected token <` for all of the `.js` files that have `jsx` in them. So seems to me that `eslint` does not like having JSX in files with extension '.js'

These are my babel eslint packages:

```
 "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.18.2",
"babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
"babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
"babel-types": "^6.18.0",
"eslint": "^3.9.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.3",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.13.2",
"webpack-middleware": "^1.5.1"
```

And these are my rules:

```
"babel": {
"presets": [
  "react",
  "latest"
],
"plugins": [
  "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
  "transform-async-to-generator",
  "transform-es2015-destructuring",
  "transform-es2015-parameters",
  "transform-es2015-duplicate-keys",
  "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
  "transform-exponentiation-operator",
  "transform-runtime"
],
"env": {
  "test": {
    "plugins": [
      "rewire"
    ]
  }
}},
```

Eslint configs:

```
"eslintConfig": {
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"extends": "airbnb",
"env": {
  "browser": true
},
"rules": {
  "jsx-quotes": [
    2,
    "prefer-double"
  ],
  "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
    1,
    {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
    }
  ],
  "react/jsx-quotes": 0,
  "react/jsx-boolean-value": 0,
  "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content": "off",
  "import/extensions": "off",
  "comma-dangle": [
    2,
    {
      "arrays": "always-multiline",
      "objects": "always-multiline",
      "imports": "always-multiline",
      "exports": "always-multiline",
      "functions": "ignore"
    }
  ],
  "no-plusplus": [
    2,
    {
      "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true
    }
  ]
}},
```

Not sure how to resolve this, I've checked other answers online but none helped. Setting specific rule 
`"rules": {
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }]
}` 
also didnt help. The code builds just fine, it just the linter fails

Comment: are you getting an error while linting or transpiling?

Comment: Am getting this as a linting error

Comment: Have you looked at this issue? https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/447#issuecomment-184617282

Comment: I did, I am doing what he suggested, am using ```"parser": "babel-eslint"``` instead of `babel` as my parser, but am still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790153/unexpected-token-import-in-webpack-config-babel-js-when-using-modules-fal). The problem was that I was not transpiling the webpack config code as .babelrc would override my configs at webpack level